# Making sense of Java's non blocking I/O

Tags: java, nio

Let's say I'm running a server, and set client SocketChannels that I accept as non blocking, and read them through a thread pool's threads. But what does that buy me? I anyway need to read the full client request before processing it, which means I need to make multiple read calls.

I've also come across articles saying that threads should block naturally so it gives a chance to other threads to run. However this won't happen in the aforementioned case as these threads will not block.

So how would non blocking IO be efficient? How to make sense of this all? Some multi-core CPU angle to it perhaps? But how?

EDIT: found a pretty good link that explains it programmatically:

http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/

Comment: For me it was a advantage that i could faster shutdown the server and had not to wait for timeouts etc.

Comment: You usually combine non-blocking read with `select()` or `poll()`. Java has `Selector` for this IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to use busy waiting (which sounds unlikely) if you want to use non-blocking you usually use a small number of threads (may be only one) and a Selector.

If you are going to use blocking IO, that is when you dedicate one or two threads per connection.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly, you're saying that if one thread gets partial response from a socket, the same thread can go ahead to get response from some other socket, in a possibly round-robin fashion. So we do not need one thread per request processing. Makes sense!

Comment: That is true, but making it work, is more complicated than using one thread per blocking socket.

Answer (score 3):

The problem using blocking IO starts when you want to scale your server program. You'd have to hold a blocking thread-per-request. Many many requests will introduce man many threads. This might make some hard time for a server application that serves thousands and more of IO involving concurrent requests.

Using nio non-blocking IO, this request-to-thread coupling is redundant. You can use any thread to complete the IO operation of any request. This lets you use the great pooling pattern for your IO handling threads, and decrease significantly the thread creation and management overhead. On the other hand, you'd have to work harder to sustain data consistency, but that would be the price of scalability.

Comment: In case of blocking IO, I can still use a thread pool to serve requests. In the worst case where all threads are blocked, new requests will just get queued to be processed later. In case of non blocking IO, a thread will get only those many bytes which were available when it called read(), so it may need to make multiple reads before processing, plus this will usually increase the scheduling overhead if I use a thread pool in this case. So would it still be superior to blocking IO?

Comment: (1) This "worst case" actually the average case for which you'd use non-blocking IO. Blocking IO in that case is not-an-option, as it fails to scale. (2) Making multiple reads in non-blocking IO is very likely, disregarding the underlying thread policy. (3) Of course there's a penalty for using more than one thread, but blocking IO is  just impractical.